# Configuring PHPMyAdmin on OSX Mountain Lion using Homebrew

Tags: macos, phpmyadmin, homebrew

I'm setting up a local web server on OSX Mountain Lion. I'm currently using the version of PHP that ships with OSX, and have installed MySQL and Apache with Homebrew ([http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/](https://brew.sh/)).

The server is running fine, but I'm struggling to get PHPMyAdmin installed. Homebrew seems to have downloaded the PHPMyAdmin files to `/usr/local/Cellar/phpmyadmin/3.5.2.1/share/phpmyadmin`, but despite following a couple of tutorials I can't get `http://localhost/~jim/phpmyadmin` (`http://localhost/~jim/` is my webroot) to point to this directory.

I'm guessing the problem is something to do with httpd.conf or a Virtual Hosts configuration file, but I'm not sure how to configure these to get the result that I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin`. By default it shouldn't install in your home directory.

Comment: Thanks, I had to play with httpd.conf and a couple of other files, but I have now got PHPMyAdmin working on that path :)

Answer (score 3):

Please read the messages output by homebrew after you run `homebrew install phpmyadmin`
The messages output actually tell you what to do.
Here is the relevant part of the message.

```
Webserver configuration example (add this at the end of
your /etc/apache2/httpd.conf for instance) :

Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

Then, open http://localhost/phpmyadmin

More documentation : file:///usr/local/Cellar/phpmyadmin/4.0.4/share/phpmyadmin/Documentation.html
```

Comment: After installing phpmyadmin with homebrew, I followed all instructions, restarated apache2, restarted my machine, and still not loading.